# Legally use CDATA in XML

Tags: xml, cdata

I have an XML file which XML parser choke on.
A part of it is :

```
<closedDeal><customer><![CDATA[ABC ]]></customer></closedDeal>
```

The error I got is

```
The literal string ']]>' is not allowed in element content. Error processing resource
```

What is the correct way of using CDATA?
I need CDATA because the data is read from Excel, and could contain illegal character such as ALT+ENTER whitespace.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code that causes the error?

Comment: Ya, the error was in some other place that i didnt post here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What parser are you using? The sample you showed is definitely a valid XML. For example in .NET I successfully parsed this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<closedDeal>
  <customer><![CDATA[ABC ]]></customer>
</closedDeal>
```

using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
        doc.XPathSelectElement("//customer");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: err.. ok thanks.
the error was in longer code that I didnt put here. There was closing ]]> but no opening <!CDATA[ somewhere. Your confirmation that it should work helped to encourage me to debug. Thanks.