# Is the ]]> sequence really not legal in the content of an XML-tag?

Tags: xml, escaping, standards

I have an XML document with a tag that contains a user entered message, I would like to avoid unnecessary escaping of characters.

According to the link below the only strictly illegal characters are "<" and "&".

> **Note**: Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML.
> The greater than character is legal, but it is a good habit to replace it.
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

But in some parsers i encountered problems with the sequence ]]>, is this due to problems with the parsers or is it really defined as illegal somewhere in the XML-standard?

Example message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<root>
  <message>&lt;!-- -- -- &lt;![CDATA[&quot;TEST&quot;]]></message>
  <signature>Evil</signature>
</root>
```

As you can see < and & are escaped and this message is successfully parsed by C++ tinyxml and Java JAXB. Both Firefox 20.0.1 and IE 8.0 tell me

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

and

> The literal string ']]>' is not allowed in element content.

respectively.

Is this really a standard enforced behavior?

**EDIT:** Should have searched some more it seems, [Legally use CDATA in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468327/legally-use-cdata-in-xml). So I guess the XML parser in Firefox and IE are just broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) (emphasis mine):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" and "`&lt;`" respectively. **The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string "`&gt;`", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string "`]]>`" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.**

This means as long as the `]]>` delimiter is not being used to mark the end of a CDATA section *for use by the XML parser reading this document*, it is not legal without being escaped, even if it isn't occurring within the context of a CDATA section.

I'm not familiar with the XML parsers used internally by browsers, but seeing as this requirement is in place for compatibility reasons, your guess seems sound.